# Mod Rewrite with 2 similar rewrite cond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

so I want 2 different rewrite rules.

First:

http://mydomain.com/affiliate/533/1  ->  http://mydomain.com/affiliate/index.php?member=533&campaign=1

Second:

http://mydomain.com/affiliate/533/2/1   -> http://mydomain.com/templates/2/step1.php?member=533

The following .htaccess gives 500 Internal Server error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^affiliate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) affiliate/index.php?member=$1&campaign=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^affiliate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/step([0-9])+) templates/$2/step$3.php?member=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/step([0-9])+)? There's no "step" in your second base url. Also an extra closing parenthesis. Maybe you mean ^affiliate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your example with a clean server install.

As long as I don't use `Options +FollowSymlinks` in `.htaccess` it works fine with only `AllowOverride FileInfo`.

When using `Options +FollowSymlinks` in `.htaccess` I need `AllowOverride Options FileInfo` in my `<Directory  >` entry.

So, it seems not to be a bug.

Comment: But then again, the Apache manual says: "To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled. If your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine. This restriction is required for security reasons." So the root cause is that FollowSymLinks is not allowed and should be set in a <Directory> context.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your config and my error.log told me "RewriteEngine not allowed here".

After adding a "AllowOverride All" to that test directory the error went away.
However, the Apache manual at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule says:

> To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set
>   "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled. If
>   your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a
>   user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine. This
>   restriction is required for security reasons.

So the correct way would be setting up a  and setting the FollowSymLinks option there.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the parenthesis, which, in turn, when Apache tries the last Regexp, generates an error, thus an internal error, which ouputs a 500. So here's the version that should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^affiliate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) affiliate/index.php?member=$1&campaign=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^affiliate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/step(([0-9])+) templates/$2/step$3.php?member=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Where is the difference except that you added an extra closing paranthesis?